# Add title to daterangepicker cell based on class

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Thanks to function isCustomDate from plugin **daterangepicker**, I can add custom class to a cell.

css:

```
.holiday {background-color:red;}
```

code:

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
isCustomDate: function(e) {
        var dataCell = moment(e._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        if ( dataCell == "2015-01-01" ) {
            return 'holiday newyear';
        }
        if ( dataCell == "2015-12-25" ) {
            return 'holiday xmas';
        }

    }
});
```

Now i'd like to add a title, based on class added. If there is a class "xmas", add `title="Christmas day"`. Any idea?

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9qdbaxo/

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  $(picker.container[0]).find(".holiday").attr("title","Vacanza");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9qdbaxo/1/

UPDATE: it doesn't work if the holiday's day in in another month and i need to scroll calendar left or right......
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/h9qdbaxo/2/

Answer (score 0):

Very Tricky Solution

```
let dateTimePicker = $('.bulk_dt_time_picker');
  dateTimePicker.daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePicker24Hour: true,
    minDate: moment(),
    startDate: this.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.StartDate + ' '+ tod[0],
    endDate: this.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.EndDate + ' ' + tod[1],
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MMM-YY HH:mm'
    }
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    _self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.StartDate = start.format('DD-MMM-YY');
    _self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.EndDate = end.format('DD-MMM-YY');
    let timeStart = start.format('HH:mm');
    let timeEnd = end.format('HH:mm');
    if (timeStart != timeEnd) {
      _self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.ToD = timeStart + ' - ' + timeEnd;;
    } else {
      _self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.ToD = timeStart;
    }
    dateTimePicker.each(function(){
      $(this).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(_self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.StartDate + ' '+ timeStart);
      $(this).data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(_self.TestsetItems.SchedulerItems.EndDate + ' ' + timeEnd);
    });
  }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(picker.container[0]).find(".calendar.right .calendar-time div").empty();
    $(ev.target).data('daterangepicker').renderTimePicker('right');
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).